# What is the most difficult block to obtain in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to host a competition where my friends go and collect materials to make a block. In order to make it more difficult, I wanted to make them get it.

Except for command blocks, structure voids and all other unobtainable blocks, which block is the hardest block to obtain?

For example: an Emerald ore block is hard to get, as Emerald ores are rare.

Comment: Hi Dreadlord, can you clarify what you mean by 'hardest'? Do you mean rare? riskiest to your character's life? Blocks that require special conditions to obtain, like needing Silk Touch? Blocks that have many rare source components? Do you differentiate between "objects" (beacons, fences etc) vs natural blocks (stone, grass, diamond ore etc)?

Comment: Regarding @Robotnik edit: Emerald block is vastly easier to obtain than an Emerald Ore block. Somehow I think this wasn't OP's intent.

Comment: @SF. Oh yes, Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you consider using glitches, the [recently obtained Bedrock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHdSpO-Gsvc&t) in Java Edition is the most difficult to obtain actually obtained block. [A viable theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTbpUjK-A74) about how to obtain spawners, End portal frames and such has been developed but nobody has been successful in constructing the necessary contraption in survival so far.

Netherite block, while requiring quite a bit of effort, isn't actually difficult at all - after you've descended to y=8 in the Nether, basic caution against lava and patience with digging will get you the required 36 Ancient Debris, and transforming them into Netherite at that point is trivial. Comparing the amount of time and effort in a new world, I'd say Mycelium is more rare and sponges are more dangerous and difficult to obtain. Even stupid Conduit in 1.16 after the fishing farm nerf got sufficiently difficult it tops Netherite in difficulty.

Dragon head, if counting effort and difficulty 'from start to finish' would be the top block, but it usually 'happens in the process' - it isn't a goal by itself, it just appears near other, more desirable endgame goals. Another hard-to-obtain block is a creeper head - killing a creeper through explosion of a charged creeper requires plenty of effort if you don't already have a channeling trident.

The Beacon is probably most challenging though. First, you must kill an obscene amount of wither skeletons - on average 54 if you have a Looting 3 sword, or 120 without. This done in a Nether Fortress which is rather challenging. It can be automated but building a farm by itself is quite a bit of a challenge. Then you must construct a Wither and kill it. It's possible to 'cheese' this fight but it's probably more difficult than the Ender Dragon fight if done 'legit'.

Comment: can you link to obtaining bedrock and theory of obtaining spawners/frames/and such, please?

Comment: @NooneAtAll I've linked the bedock item video explaining the concept (note it's only possible in 1.12). I can't find the portal frames link currently - I've seen it on one of discords of technical minecraft. Note it may still be impossible due to technicalities like the fact end portal frames spawn deep under ground.

Comment: @NooneAtAll Coolmann24 just released a video detailing the theory behind obtaining arbitrary blocks. I've linked it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Risk-wise, the single most difficult block to obtain is the activated Regeneration Beacon, since there are many steps to it, and many of these steps are very risky to make.

Compared to Netherite, it may not take as long to obtain, but it's definitely harder to do so. Here's why:

- You have to get into the Nether, which requires getting diamond tools to build a portal.
- You have to find a fortress and get to it safely.
- You have to obtain 3 wither skulls, which involves killing Wither Skeletons that have a 2.5% chance of dropping a Skull, so you will have to kill 120 Wither Skeletons on average. You can speed up your progress by getting Looting on your weapon, but that also takes a lot of time.
- Next you have to build and fight the Wither, which is the single most difficult mob to defeat to get a nether star.
- Finally, craft the Beacon and build 164 mineral blocks underneath it and activate it with a single mineral in addition to have Regeneration activated on the Beacon.

Keep in mind that this is still one single block, even though it requires other blocks (the mineral pyramid beneath) to be in this state.

Comment: You can get into the nether with stone tools, a bucket, and a flint and steel.  Diamond tools aren't needed.  Using buckets, a portal can be built in about the same amount of time it takes to mine just 2 blocks of obsidian.

Comment: @MBraedley yes, but I'm going with the standard procedure, because you might want to have diamond tools and armor when fighting Wither Skeletons, or even the Wither itself. And I think OP isn't looking for a speedrunner's guide to this ;)

Comment: All beacons are the same block.

Comment: @user253751 not really. A redstone torch can also be lit and unlit and have different effects, yet it's the same block. I think the Beacon is a similar case.

Comment: @Quijibo Yes, and? All redstone torches are also the same block (since the flattening). Therefore you don't say that unlit redstone torches are harder to obtain than lit ones or vice versa.

Comment: @MBraedley: You need a diamond or netherite pick to obtain 3 obsidian necessary in the beacon recipe. Unless you're quite lucky with chests.

Comment: @user253751 By that logic, a single wooden slab is the same block as a double wooden slab. But they've got different drops, so surely that can't be? Or, say, potions; are _they_ all the same item?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 By the answer's logic, the hardest block to get is not a netherite block, but a chest full of shulker boxes full of netherite blocks.

Comment: @user253751 So we should probably fall back to something like "looks different", or "behaves differently", or something (where "behaves differently" is running different code, and not just having different data; otherwise, books would probably win).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 They do behave differently. If you open one and click on the first slot, you get a shulker full of netherite blocks. That's the difference between a chest full of shulker boxes full of netherite blocks, and an empty chest.

Comment: @user253751 There's no dispatch in the code, though; that's all user-generated data.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 There is one based on whether the slot has *any* item, so does a full chest (of the cheapest item) count as more difficult than an empty one? There is also a dispatch based on whether the item is stackable.

Comment: @user253751 Perhaps; a trapped double chest full of wooden spades (or, alternatively, snowballs / eggs / dirt) is the trickiest thing I can think of by that definition, though, so it seems moot.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 A double-chest is two blocks, each of which stores half the items. But you can indeed make it slightly more difficult by requiring the single trapped chest block in question to be in a double-chest state. Snowballs, eggs and dirt are stackable.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Netherite. Netherite requires four blocks of smelted Ancient Debris (Netherite Scrap) and four blocks of smelted Gold Ore (Gold Ingots) to make one Netherite Ingot. This means you have to do this nine times to get a Netherite block.

It is so hard to get that Mr Beast made [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJp8thYqiOQ) about it.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this to be the most difficult. Other blocks like sponges and conduits are much rarer from a density perspective. Dragon eggs and beacons could also be considered hard to obtain due to the bosses required to be defeated (you could say this is in the same vain as sponges)

Comment: I understand, however I assumed he meant that it was the rarest.

Answer (score 2):

If one netherite block is hard to get, then a shulker box full of netherite blocks is even harder, and a chest full of shulker boxes full of netherite blocks is harder still.

Using this method, 46656 netherite blocks can be stored in one block, equivalent to 419904 netherite ingots, costing 1679616 gold and 1679616 ancient debris. Plus the shulker boxes.

Comment: I think we can take this even further. Having many of the same block in the shulker boxes in the chest is much easier than say, having different colored shulker boxes, all of them named, with some of the hardest items to get inside them, not just nethterite.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the hardest to get in the game is the dragon egg. The only one of it's kind that only has one of it, as well as it being "unmineable" (cause you have to drop it on a slab). Its also guarded by the ender dragon, so that poses another issue.